# Count the number of times each value appears in a column

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to count the number of times each value appears in a column in a mysql database, and then output it.

My code:

```
require("db_connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT name, q1_MC, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8_MC FROM commenttable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["q1_MC"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q2"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q3"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q4"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q5"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q6"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q7"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q8_MC"] . "</td></tr>";



}

} else { 

    echo "0 results"; 

}


$conn->close();
```

So q1_MC and q2_MC are the columns whose fields frequency i want to count. They take numbers from 1-5.

I've been trying to incorporate the following array into my code somehow, but i dont know how.

```
$a=array("1","2","3","4","5");
print_r(array_count_values($a));
```

Comment: What about changing your sql query to count each values ?

Comment: may be [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: As MySQL is involved in the question, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: .. but seeing the increments usage in the column names (`q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7,`) you can better normalize your table.

Comment: ^^^^ Everything he said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there in the end. I use the array_count_values php function then loop through the array using the foreach function.

```
$q1_MC = array();
$q8_MC = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


    $counts = array('q1_MC' => array(0,0,0,0,0), 'q8_MC' => array(0,0,0,0,0));


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


    array_push($q1_MC, $row['q1_MC']);
    array_push($q8_MC, $row['q8_MC']);


 echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["q1_MC"] . "</td><td>" 
. $row["q2"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q3"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q4"] . "</td> . 
 <td>" 
. $row["q5"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q6"] . "</td><td>" . $row["q7"] . "</td> 
.    <td>" 
. $row["q8_MC"] . "</td></tr>";

    }

} else { 

    echo "0 results"; 

}

$q1_answers = (array_count_values($q1_MC));
$q2_answers = (array_count_values($q8_MC));

echo "<div class='row mt-5 mb-5 mr-4 ml-4'>";
echo "<table class='table' id='questionsTable'><thead><tr><th>Question 1 
Multiple Choice answers</th></tr>";

foreach($q1_answers as $key => $item) {

echo "<tr><td>" . $key. "</td><td>" . $item. "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tr></table></div>";


echo "<div class='row mt-5 mb-5 mr-4 ml-4'>";
echo "<table class='table' id='questionsTable'><thead><tr><th>Question 8 
Multiple Choice answers</th></tr>";

foreach($q2_answers as $key => $item) {

echo "<tr><td>" . $key. "</td><td>" . $item. "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tr></table></div>";
```

Comment: If this is what solved your problem you should accept your own answer (unfortunately you don't get any reputation for that).

Answer (score 2):

You could use sql for obtain the result you need  in SQL you could count distinct and group by eg for q1_MC and q2_MC you could use

```
SELECT name, count(distinct q1_MC)  freq1 ,  count(distinct q8_MC) freq8
FROM commenttable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'q2_MC' in 'field list' in phpmyadmin. How much of that query do i need to edit?

Comment: `q2_MC` typo? Try `q8_MC` ?  @RhysEdwards